# nm type g and G

Tags: elf, nm

Following `man nm` it's written the following:

```
"G"

"g"

The symbol is in an initialized data section for small objects.
Some object file formats permit more efficient access to small data objects,
such as a global int variable as opposed to a large global array.
```

What section does it correspond to "initialized data section for small objects"?